# SQL WHERE clause issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The problem I am having seems to come from my where clause and hardcoding.
I have two tables one with ID's and another with ID's and Scores for the ID's.

So my code looks a little something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(c.Score AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestC,
       AVG(CAST(d.Score AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestD,
       AVG(CAST(e.Score AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestE,
       AVG(CAST(f.Score AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestF,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS CountC,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.ID) AS CountD,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.ID) AS CountE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.ID) AS CountF
FROM tblWithIds a,
     JOIN tblScores b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Year = @Year
     LEFT JOIN tblScores c ON a.ID = c.ID AND c.Year = @Year
     LEFT JOIN tblScores d ON a.ID = d.ID AND d.Year = @Year
     LEFT JOIN tblScores e ON a.ID = e.ID AND e.Year = @Year
     LEFT JOIN tblScores f ON a.ID = f.ID AND f.Year = @Year
WHERE c.TestC = 'Test C'
      d.TestD = 'Test D'
      e.TestE = 'Test E'
      f.TestF = 'Test F'
```

Now the problem is that when I add more to the where clause and almost identical "Tests" the where clause, it gives me NULL values for everything and 0's for the COUNT. The code above works properly but the test am I using have very similar names and the table was made poorly so all of the "Tests" names' are all in one column. I cannot debug as I am stuck using MSSQL 05 for now. Please help!

EDIT: After getting using the aggregate function SUM below from EricZ, if anyone else is interested I have found that

```
AVG( CASE WHEN b.Test = 'Test D' THEN CAST(b.Score AS DEC(10,2)) ELSE NULL END) AS avgTestC
```

to be the correct form for the AVG aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE to do COUNT, and just need JOIN table once

```
SELECT 
       AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN b.TestC = 'Test C' THEN b.Score ELSE 0 END) AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestC,
       AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN b.TestD = 'Test D' THEN b.Score ELSE 0 END) AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestD,
       AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN b.TestE = 'Test E' THEN b.Score ELSE 0 END) AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestE,
       AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN b.TestF = 'Test F' THEN b.Score ELSE 0 END) AS DEC(10,2))) AS avgTestF,             
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.TestC = 'Test C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountC,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.TestD = 'Test D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS CountD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.TestE = 'Test E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS CountE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.TestF = 'Test F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS CountF
FROM tblWithIds a,
JOIN tblScores b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Year = @Year
```

Comment: This works however you didn't put the AVG in there as well. I'm not sure how to solve that for the average portion.

Comment: Thanks lol I actually figured it out in the allotted time :P but it works and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE instead

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Something > 0 THEN Something ELSE 0 END) AS A, SUM(CASE WHEN Something2 > 0 THEN Something2 ELSE 0 END) AS B
```

Comment: I'd like to not use recursion in order to complete the task, I need to have all the averaged "Scores" in my results and in order to do that I need to be able to get the "Scores" from all of the tests.

Comment: its not recursion. its set-logic. you can use AVG or any other aggregate function there

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted what you were trying to get across thank you, EricZ just put it in the 5 year old standard so I could understand.